# Function specialization with array argument

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to specialize a function for a specific array type?

For example having a template function:

```
template <typename T, size_t size>
void process(T (&arr)[size])
{
    // do smth
}
```

Could a function specialization for `T=uint8_t` be done in such case? Or is the only reasonable solution here to use an overload like the one below?

```
template <size_t size>
void process(uint8_t (&arr)[size])
{
    // do smth else
}
```

Thanks for suggestions and comments.

Comment: Thanks for the tip and pointing me to the right post.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to specialize function templates partially, so you will probably have to use a separate overload.